# How to loop Outlook emails with particular subject line?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that extracts the body of email which has the subject line "Volume data".

Let's say I have 10 emails in my inbox folder which has the subject line "Volume data".
I want to loop through all the emails, find which email has subject line "Volume data" and then extract the email body from those 10 emails.
My code is stopping at the first instance where it finds the mentioned subject.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub impOutlookTable()

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents

' point to the desired email
Const strMail As String = "emailaddress"

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim destCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim oItem As Object

With ActiveSheet
    Set destCell = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
If (oApp Is Nothing) Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")

On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")
Set oMail = oMapi.Items(oMapi.Items.Count)

For Each oItem In oMapi.Items
    If oItem.Subject = "Volume data" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next oItem

If Not oItem Is Nothing Then

    ' get html table from email object
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable

    Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    With HTMLdoc
        .Body.innerHTML = oItem.HTMLBody
        Set tables = .getElementsByTagName("table")
    End With

    'import in Excel
    For Each table In tables
        For x = 0 To table.Rows.Length - 1
            For y = 0 To table.Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                destCell.Offset(x, y).Value = table.Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
            Next y
        Next x
        Set destCell = destCell.Offset(x)
    Next
End If

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oMapi = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing
Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
Set tables = Nothing

wkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\Desktop\New_email.xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to put all of the "Action" code inside the `If` statement in your loop instead of after it, and then remove the `Exit For`

Comment: Can you please help me understand further. I am not too familiar with VBA. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all of the "Action" code inside the `If` statement inside your loop instead of after it, and then remove the `Exit For`.

You will also need a counter or something so that you aren't just saving overtop of the same file for each iteration.

**UNTESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub impOutlookTable()
Dim iCounter As Integer
iCounter = 1
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents

' point to the desired email
Const strMail As String = "emailaddress"

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim destCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim oItem As Object

With ActiveSheet
Set destCell = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")
If (oApp Is Nothing) Then Set oApp = CreateObject("OUTLOOK.APPLICATION")

On Error GoTo 0

Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")
Set oMail = oMapi.Items(oMapi.Items.Count)

For Each oItem In oMapi.Items
    If oItem.Subject = "Volume data" Then

        ' get html table from email object
        Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable


        Set HTMLdoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        With HTMLdoc
            .Body.innerHTML = oItem.HTMLBody
            Set tables = .getElementsByTagName("table")
        End With


        'import in Excel
        For Each table In tables
            For x = 0 To table.Rows.Length - 1
                For y = 0 To table.Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                    destCell.Offset(x, y).Value = table.Rows(x).Cells(y).innerText
                Next y
            Next x
            Set destCell = destCell.Offset(x)
        Next


        Set oApp = Nothing
        Set oMapi = Nothing
        Set oMail = Nothing
        Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
        Set tables = Nothing

        wkb.SaveAs "C:\Users\Desktop\New_email_" & iCounter & ".xlsm"
        iCounter = iCounter + 1
    
    End If
Next oItem

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou! I am getting an error that says an attempted operation failed. An object could not be found. This error is showing in the line where I am setting oMapi....'Set oMapi = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(strMail).Folders("inbox")'

Comment: Well that's a separate issue then. Is `strMail` holding the value that you expect? Is it valid? You currently have it set to `"emailaddress"` which is probably not right.

Comment: Yes, I have changed it according to my email address. For now the code runs fine, the only thing is it is still not looping across all the items in the inbox. It is still looking at the first instance with the subject line "Volume data". Any idea on that?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than one email with the subject line "Volume data"? The way you have it coded, it will only run on emails that have that exact subject. It can't have anything else in the subject.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that I have more than one email. All the emails have the same subject line. It's a recurring email that we get every day. So the subject remains exactly the same.

Comment: Then put a breakpoint on the `If` statement and step through it.

Comment: I do have one more code which runs on a particular subfolder. So i had directed all the emails with subject line "Volume data" to a subfolder in inbox. That code doesn't need a subject line condition as that folder contains only those emails which has the subject line as "volume data". But i need to generalize the code, so that even if the emails are in the Inbox folder itself, based on the subject line of the email it should extract the body of that email.

Comment: How do i put a breakpoint on the If statement? Sorry, just a beginner in VBA. Can you please explain further?

Comment: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Comment: thankyou for your help! :)

Comment: Sure, I have added. Thanks again!